# How do I make a button that clears the content of the page divison?

Tags: html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQjLI.jpg)

I manage to get the buttons to show text and numbers on the bottom of the page, but I can't remove it without having to reload the page. I want to add a button that can remove it without having the website be reloaded every time. I heard something about using inner.html or something to be the empty string but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: code must add code, but not as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this working well.
```

```html
<h3>My Binary Calculator</h3>

<p>Simply click on the buttons to calculate how many different unique values can be represented with n bits. </p>

<input type="button" value="n=1" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + '2 values <br/>';">
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="n=2" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + '4 values <br/>';">
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="n=3" onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + '6 values <br/>';">
<br/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Clear all"
onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML= '';">
<br/><br/>

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```